# Is there an English-Russian translator?

Tags: software-recommendation, translation

Can anybody recommend me english-russian translator for ubuntu 11.10. I need to translate in program, not in web browser with online translators.

Comment: ...and what do you want to translate in program, ...and in which program???

Comment: If it is a specific program check if it has a launchpad translation page :)

Comment: Machine translation is a hard problem. While there is software and even whole distributions of Linux targeted at providing utility to human translators, machine translation software is thin on the ground.

Google offer an API for Google Translate which you could utilise in your application, but this is now only available as a paid service.

Answer (score 1):

Performing a simple search on the "Ubuntu Software center" using the word "translator" you can find some useful tools,

[image]

which includes (but not limits to):

## [Language Translator](http://www.nongnu.org/libtranslate/gnome-translate/)

[image]

From the official site:

> GNOME Translate is a GNOME interface to libtranslate. It can translate
>   a text or web page between several natural languages, and it can
>   automatically detect the source language as you type.
>
> GNOME Translate is free software, released under the terms of the GNU
>   General Public License.

Somehow, the screenshot provided inside of the description is showing an example of a text in Russian, being translated to English, and several other languages are available to translate in both directions.

[image]

I am sure you can find some other useful tools in order to fit your needs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any one. If you have already used one, (may be in Windows) you can use WINE app to run Windows applications in Ubuntu.